# Euclidean isometries

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am asked to show that every translation of the euclidean plane can be written as two reflections.

How do I proceed (algebraicly)?

My idea is to proof it in a sense of creating a rectangular triangle which creates the translation vector as the resulting vector of two reflections.

Comment: Do you understand the idea?

Comment: @SuzuHirose yes I hope so :) but I dont know how to put it algebraicly correct

Comment: can you show that any translation of the ordinary real line is two reflections? Suppose i have a fixed real number $A.$ Given other real $x,$ what value do you get by reflecting $x$ across $A?$ For example, with fixed $A=3,$ the reflection of $x=2$ is $x=4;$ the reflection of $x=7$ is $x=-1.$

Comment: @Mainviel Take a line midway between two points A and B and perpendicular to the line joining A and B. Reflect around it. Then reflect around a parallel line through B. Then you have a translation from A to B. If I had to do this algebraically I would go along X axis with first point at origin then finagle that with rotations and translations.

Comment: @WillJagy I am not quite sure but I would say $x' = x + 2 \cdot \vert A-x \vert$ ?

Comment: Almost..................; no absolute values are involved. Meanwhile, if you reflect $x$ and then reflect the result, you must get back exactly to $x$

Comment: @WillJagy without the absolute values i see thank you. But still how to prove it algebraicly?

Comment: Pick a translation in the real line and choose fixed $A,B$ that do the job; a reflection across $A$ followed by a reflection across $B$ giving the same as the translation you chose. Oh: what is the formula for a translation in the real line?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Suppose $A(a, b)$ is the object and $B(a’, b’)$ is its image after a translation (the dotted line).

Locate the (green) line which is $L_1 : x = \frac {a + a’}{2}$

Locate the (blue) line which is $L_2 : y = \frac {b + b’}{2}$

A is first reflected about the $L_1$ to $C$ and then reflected about $L_2$ to $B$.